# Creating a class to extend for an API

Tags: java, api, extend

I am trying to create an API in java for my Uni project.

Is the following possible.

I have 2 versions of `MyClass` where one does not contain code in the method bodies.

for example:

Full Version:

```
public MyClass {
     public String name;

     public MyClass(String name) {
          this.name = name;
     }

     public String getSpecialVersion(){
         return name + name;
     }
}
```

API Version:

```
public MyClass {
     public String name;

     public MyClass(String name) {}

     public String getSpecialVersion(){ return null; }
}
```

The idea being a user extends the API version of the class, but the full version of the class is loaded at runtime.

Is this possible in Java, or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you want to use an interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create an **interface** and let the "with code"-version **implement** that interface.

```
public interface IMyClass {

    public String getSpecialVersion();

}
```

Implementation:

```
public class MyClass implements IMyClass {

    public String name;

    public MyClass(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpecialVersion() {
        return name + name;
    }

}
```

You cannot define constructors in interfaces (and defining fields in interfaces is kind of unconventional) tho, so you might want to look at **abstract classes** for that, too:

```
public abstract class AbstractMyClass {

    public String name;

    public AbstractMyClass(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract String getSpecialVersion();

}
```

This class can be **extended** by a concrete class to add the method body:

```
public class MyClass extends AbstractMyClass {

    public MyClass(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpecialVersion() {
        return name + name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ahh I didn't think about using Abstract classes. But thinking about it, I shouldn't really have public fields like that!! I'll try to refactor out an interface :) cheers

Comment: If you want an implementation of an interface loaded at run-time and you do not want the full power/complexity of Dependency Injection frameworks such as Guice or Spring, you could look at the ServiceLoader built into the JDK - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?index-filesindex-1.html